# How to include DW Question & Answer plugin in front page template?

Tags: plugins, shortlink

I tried using a shortlink code, but only the link is displaying and it isn't working either.

```
<?php the_shortlink('http://abc.com/?p=52'); ?>
```

I am using **DW Question & Answer** plugin and want to show question answer page in my blog. How to do it?

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you want users to be able to ask and answer questions in your fontend?

Comment: Do you know if the pages created has a shortcode? for example [QWQA ASK] or [QWQA QUESTION] if you have this shortcode you can copy and paste it to the front page to be displayes with your other content.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want your users to be able to ask questions in the front end: you can add the page for asking questions to your menu real easy. Just use the menu functionality of Wordpress:

[image]

Click DWQA Ask Question and then Add to Menu. This is built-in functionality of the DW Question & Answer plugin.